# MKMapView Zoom to Fit Overlays

Tags: ios, mkmapview, zooming, overlay, mkoverlay

I have an circle overlay on my MKMap, which the user can change the radius of. How can I make it so when the radius is changed the Map will automatically zoom to fit the new radius size.

I have tried:

```
_mapView.visibleMapRect = circleOverlay.boundingMapRect;
```

But it zooms in too far and the stroke around my circle overlay is cut off at the top and bottom. Can someone give me any help on how to fix this please?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try:

```
_mapView.visibleMapRect = [_mapView mapRectThatFits:circleOverlay.boundingMapRect];
```

or even `mapRectThatFits:edgePadding:` to get a little extra space around the edges.

Comment: I get an error when I try that line: No visible @interface for 'MKMapView' declares the selector 'rectThatFits' What does that mean?

Comment: Sorry, it's mapRectThatFits:, fixing the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, it has fixed it! Thank you so much for the quick response too! Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to David Berry's answer, this lets you animate the zoom:

`[self.mapView setVisibleMapRect:[self.mapView mapRectThatFits:circleOverlay.boundingMapRect] edgePadding:UIEdgeInsetsMake(5.0f, 5.0f, 5.0f, 5.0f) animated:YES];`